# Regex Invalid Group

Tags: javascript, regex

Can anyone see why this is giving an `Invalid regular expression: Invalid group` error?

```
text.replace(/(?<!br|p|\/p|b|\/b)>/g, "&gt;");
```

This one is OK:

```
text.replace(/<(?!br|p|\/p|b|\/b)/g, "&lt;");
```

So, I'm not sure where I'm going wrong with the first one (`&gt;`).

Here's a [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/DP32f/) with an example.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

JavaScript does not support lookbehinds.  Here is one way you can get the same behavior:

```
text = text.replace(/(br|p|\/p|b|\/b)?>/g, function($0, $1){
    return $1 ? $0 : "&gt;";
});
```

This approach comes from the following blog entry: [Mimicking Lookbehind in JavaScript](http://blog.stevenlevithan.com/archives/mimic-lookbehind-javascript)

Here is an updated [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/rPqgm/).